# Custom list of hypotheses in table of contents format

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems

**The Context:**
I am writing a multi-chapter scientific report with many numbered hypotheses.
I have created a custom hypothesis environment in the preamble:

`\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}[chapter]`

An example of a hypothesis in the body of the document is:

```
\begin{hypothesis}
\label{HXonY}
There is a positive relationship between X and Y.
\end{hypothesis}
```

**My Question:**
How can I create a custom List of Hypotheses like a Table of Contents that lists:

- the hypothesis number (e.g.,1.1, 1.2, 2.1, etc.)
- the text of each hypothesis in the document
- the page number where it is recorded

E.g.,

```
 List of Hypotheses
 1.1 There is a positive relationship between X and Y .................. 32
 1.2 There is a negative relationship between something and Z........... 43
```

etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't get any of the theorem packages to produce such a list directly. So the following produces its own list using the tools provided by `ntheorem`. It works by adding lines directly to the list of `hypolist` theorems.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{hypo}{Hypothesis}[chapter]
\newtheorem{hypolist}{Hypothesis}[chapter]

\newcommand*\hypothesis[1]{%
    \stepcounter{hypolist}%
    \addtheoremline{hypolist}{#1}%
    \begin{hypo}#1\end{hypo}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of Hypotheses}
\listtheorems{hypolist}

\chapter{foo}

\hypothesis{There is a positive relationship between $X$ and $Y$.}

\chapter{bar}

\hypothesis{There is a positive relationship between $X$ and $Z$.}
\hypothesis{There is a positive relationship between $Z$ and $Y$.}

\end{document}
```

[image: the list]

I defined a command instead of an environment, because it is simpler and you can't use multi-paragraph entries in the list anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The `ntheorem` package can do this:

```
\listtheorems{hypothesis}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. However, by default it does not print the hypothesis text in the list. It only prints the hypothesis number and the page number. I'm having a read through the documentation to see if it supports printing the text.

Comment: It seems to take the list text from any text in square brackets: e..g., \begin{hypothesis}[This text is displayed in list]This text is not\end{hypothesis}. While I would be willing to type the text twice if necessary, the text in the square brackets also appears in my document, which prevents it from being a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [thmtools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/thmtools.html) package (note the different syntax for creating new theorems).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{hypothesis}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Hypotheses}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={hypothesis}]

\chapter{foo}

\begin{hypothesis}[X-Y-relationship]
There is a positive relationship between X and Y.
\end{hypothesis}

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This produces “X-Y-relationship” in the list, while the OP wanted “There is a positive relationship between X and Y.”

Answer (score 1):

In the end I decided to use [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/).
I.e., I have an Rnw file with tex and R code chunks which acts as a pre-processor for a LaTeX document.

I have a csv file which stores the hypotheses with one hypothesis per row:

```
  hypotheses <- read.csv("hypotheses.csv")
```

The following R function outputs the latex for the hypothesis environment:

```
outputHypothesis <- function(label, data = hypotheses) {
    result <- c("\\begin{hypothesis}",
            paste("\\label{", label, "}"),
            data[data$label==label, "text"],
            "\\end{hypothesis}")
    cat(result, sep="\n")
}
```

Then the Rnw file has an R code chunk which inserts the tex:

```
<<results=tex>>=
outputHypothesis("H1XcausesY")
@
```

I still have to finalise the next step of actually creating the table of  hypotheses, but I think I'll implement it as an R code chunk in Sweave.

One thing I've already done is use the database to display a table in the discussion section that uses the database of hypotheses as the source and shows (based on the database) whether the hypotheses were supported in a each of a set of studies:

```
\begin{landscape}
\singlespacing
\begin{longtable}[p]{p{2cm}p{10cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}}

\caption{Summary of Support for Hypotheses}
\label{discussionhypotheses}\\
\toprule
Number & Hypothesis & Study 1 & Study 2 & Study 3\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
Number & Hypothesis & Study 1 & Study 2 & Study 3\\
\midrule
\endhead

\multicolumn{5}{r}{\emph{Table continues on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
<<hypothesis_table, results=tex>>=
discussionHypotheses <- paste("\\ref{", hypotheses$label, "}",
        "& ", hypotheses$text,
    " & ", hypotheses$support_study1,
    " & ", hypotheses$support_study2,
    " & ", hypotheses$support_study3,
    "\\\\")
cat(discussionHypotheses, sep ="\n") 
@
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```