# Include only paragraph titles in the table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

My Latex document has a large number of `paragraph`s (about 10 per page), and I'd like to build a list of the titles of all these paragraphs.

For example, given the following document:

```
\paragraph{Bla1} Bla bla bla bla
\paragraph{Bla2} Bla bla bla bla
\paragraph{Bla3} Bla bla bla bla
\paragraph{Bla4} Bla bla bla bla
```

the output would look like

> Bla1 — Bla2 — Bla3 — Bla4

Ideas? I tried customizing the table of contents, but I can't exclude sections and subsections...

Thanks!

Comment: You should try adding `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}` to your document preamble. I'm more-or-less referring to [this entry in the UK TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=secnumdep).

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't exclude levels 1 to 4...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code shows one possibility which can be modified according to the document class used and to specific needs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Paragraph[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{prg}{Paragraph}{#1}%
  \paragraph{#1}}
\newcommand\l@Paragraph[2]{#1,~\textit{#2}}
\newcommand\listParagraphname{List of Paragraphs}
\newcommand\listofParagraphs{%
  \section*{\listParagraphname}\@starttoc{prg}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\listofParagraphs
\Paragraph{Test paragraph one}
\Paragraph{Test paragraph two}
\Paragraph{Test paragraph three}
\Paragraph{Test paragraph four}
\Paragraph{Test paragraph five}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The main points are

1. To use a newly defined command `\Paragraph` with one mandatory argument; `\Paragraph` writes its argument and the current page number (if you don't need the page number, simply remove `,~\textit{#2}` in the code below) to a new contents file with extension `.prg`; it also uses the argument as the mandatory argument of the standard  `\paragraph` command to actually typeset the paragraph ion the document.
2. To use another newly defined command `\listofParagraphs` to read the information written on the contents file `.prg` and to typeset it at the point where the command is invoked (this is done through `\@starttoc{prg}`). `\listofParagraphs` also uses `\section*` to produce a title which can be controlled by `\listParagraphname`.
3. The command `\l@Paragraph` actually typesets the entries in the new table of contents. The first argument is the title, and the second one is the page number.

To add a separator between the entries, you can use `\addtocontents`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Paragraph[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{prg}{Paragraph}{#1}%
  \paragraph{#1}}
\newcommand\l@Paragraph[2]{#1,~\textit{#2}}
\newcommand\listParagraphname{List of Paragraphs}
\newcommand\listofParagraphs{%
  \section*{\listParagraphname}\@starttoc{prg}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\AddSep{\addtocontents{prg}{--}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\listofParagraphs
\Paragraph{Test paragraph one}
\AddSep
\Paragraph{Test paragraph two}
\AddSep
\Paragraph{Test paragraph three}
\AddSep
\Paragraph{Test paragraph four}
\AddSep
\Paragraph{Test paragraph five}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: All right, Wow.

Comment: One small question : what does `\l@` do? Also, is there a way to include a separator between exercises that doesn't get added to the end of the list too?

Comment: @Clément: the command `\l@Paragraph` actually typesets the entries in the new table of contents. The first argument is the title, and the second one is the page number. For the other question, the separator, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a hack solution (adapted from [Custom list of hypotheses in table of contents format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/custom-list-of-hypotheses-in-table-of-contents-format)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{paralist}{Paragrahs}[chapter]

\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand*{\paragraph}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{paralist}%
    \addtheoremline{paralist}{#1}%
    \oldparagraph{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{List of Paragraphs}
\listtheorems{paralist}

\chapter{foo}
\paragraph{Bla1} Bla bla bla bla

\chapter{bar}
\paragraph{Bla2} Bla bla bla bla
\paragraph{Bla3} Bla bla bla bla
\paragraph{Bla4} Bla bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Kind of a hack indeed ;-)

Comment: Quite interesting =) But you loose the customization available through `tocloft` :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bizarre idea - How about switching LaTeX's interpretation of `\section` and `\paragraph`?! That way, you "upgrade" a paragraph to `tocdepth` level 1, while "downgrading" a section to `tocdepth` level 5. A little reconfiguring of the traditional formatting is necessary of all section-dependent counters (including `section` and `subsection`) though. The original definitions of `\section` and `\paragraph` were taken from the [`article` document class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {paragraph}{1}{\z@}% Sections are paragraphs
                                     {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{section}{5}{\z@}% Paragraphs are sections
                                      {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                      {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}% Section numbering
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\theparagraph.\arabic{subsection}}% Subsection numbering

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% Show only "sections"

\titlecontents*{section}[1.8pc]% "Section" formatting
  {\small}
  {\thecontentslabel. }
  {}
  {, \thecontentspage}
  [---][.]

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\paragraph{Bla1} \lipsum[1]
\paragraph{Bla2} \lipsum[2]
\paragraph{Bla3} \lipsum[3]
\paragraph{Bla4} \lipsum[4]
\paragraph{Bla5} \lipsum[5]
\paragraph{Bla6} \lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

To obtain the required formatting, only `tocdepth` level 1 items are shown (the new paragraph) using `\titlecontents*` from the [`titletoc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc).

[image: Sections as paragraphs and paragraphs as sections]

The table of contents shows the paragraph name, following by a comma `,`, the page number and a dash `---`. The last entry ends with a period `.`. This can be modified by changing the paramaters of `\titlecontents*`.

Comment: Hmmm, that's nice too =)