# Paragraph highlights before each section

Tags: sections-paragraphs

In front of each section in my book I want to have a list of highlights for some paragraph, just like in this Darwin's book:

[image]

I don't know what is the right name for this feature, that's why can't find the right LaTeX package. What is it? Which package do I need to use?

PS. I guess, I need something similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30384/include-only-paragraph-titles-in-the-table-of-contents). Here is the document structure I'm looking for:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Insects}
\section{Order Lepidoptera}
\paragraph{Courtship of butterflies}
In this great Order the most interesting point for us is the difference
in colour between the sexes of the same species, and between 
the distinct species of the same genus. Nearly the whole of 
the following chapter will be devoted to this subject.
\paragraph{Battles}
Every one has admired the extreme beauty of many butterflies and 
of some moths; and we are led to ask, how has this beauty 
been acquired?
\end{document}
```

First, I want to see this in the ToC:

```
1 Insects
1.1 Order Lepidoptera
Courtship of butterflies - Battles
```

And then, in the body of the document:

```
Chapter 1: "Insects"

Section 1.1: Order Lepidoptera

Courtship of butterflies - Battles

Courtship of butterflies.
In this great Order the most interesting point for us is the difference
in colour between the sexes of the same species, and between 
the distinct species of the same genus. Nearly the whole of 
the following chapter will be devoted to this subject.

Battles. 
Every one has admired the extreme beauty of many butterflies and 
of some moths; and we are led to ask, how has this beauty 
been acquired?
```

Comment: This looks like a table of contents by chapter. It's very easy to obtain with the `tiitlesec/titletoc` packages.

Comment: Do you want this feature automated? One would assume you're referring to using `\section`s and `\subsection`s in your document, correct? Does `386-423` represent the span of the entire `\section` within your document? Should this also be automated? Should the `\subsection`s highlighted in this "mini ToC" be hyperlinks?

Comment: Are you able to provide a document template from which one can build upon?

Comment: @Bernard I updated the question, please take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution (with pages range) using the `etoc` package (it needs two compilations to get correct tables of contents) :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoc}

\newcommand\listofparagraphsincurrentsection{%
  \begingroup%
  \etocsetlevel{subsection}{6}%
  \etocsetlevel{subsubsection}{6}%
  \etocsetlevel{subparagraph}{6}%
  \etocsetstyle{paragraph}{}%
  {\etociffirst{\edef\myfirstpage{\etocpage}}{ -- }\edef\mylastpage{\etocpage}}%
  {\etocname}{\dotfill \myfirstpage{}-\mylastpage{}}%
  \etocsettocstyle{}{}%
  \etocsettocdepth{5}%
  \localtableofcontents%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Insects}

\section{Order Lepidoptera}

\listofparagraphsincurrentsection

\paragraph{Courtship of butterflies} In this great Order the most
interesting point for us is the difference in colour between the sexes
of the same species, and between the distinct species of the same
genus. Nearly the whole of the following chapter will be devoted to this
subject.

\subsection{Test with a subsection}

\paragraph{Battles} Every one has admired the extreme beauty of many
butterflies and of some moths; and we are led to ask, how has this
beauty been acquired?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, but why `\tableofcontents` doesn't render anything?

Comment: @yegor256 You must compile twice...