# List of short problem names?

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems

I typeset a book with problems and solutions. I need to get a list of short problem names. I expected there will be a way similar to pitcures:

```
\caption[Figure name for List of Figures]{Caption name}
```

below is a summary of ways to get the list of problems.

## ntheorem

This approach seems to be closer than others:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremlisttype{all}
\newtheorem{Problem}{Problem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\listtheorems{Problem}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{Problem}[Short foo name]
  Foo!
\end{Problem}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{Problem}[Short bar name]
  Bar!
\end{Problem}

\end{document}
```

- The problem here is that the short name is also shown in the problem. Perhaps it is possible to define a new `\newtheoremlisttype`...

## thmtools

Here's a MWE thmtools (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2500/8992)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{hypothesis}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Hypotheses}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={hypothesis}]

\chapter{foo}

\begin{hypothesis}[X-Y-relationship]
There is a positive relationship between X and Y.
\end{hypothesis}

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

- There's no way to specify a name for a list of problems

## Hack

Here's MWE of some hack (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6917/8992):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{hypo}{Hypothesis}[chapter]
\newtheorem{hypolist}{Hypothesis}[chapter]

\newcommand*\hypothesis[1]{%
    \stepcounter{hypolist}%
    \addtheoremline{hypolist}{#1}%
    \begin{hypo}#1\end{hypo}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of Hypotheses}
\listtheorems{hypolist}

\chapter{foo}

\hypothesis{There is a positive relationship between $X$ and $Y$.}

\chapter{bar}

\hypothesis{There is a positive relationship between $X$ and $Z$.}
\hypothesis{There is a positive relationship between $Z$ and $Y$.}

\end{document}
```

- there's no way to specify a shorter name for the list of problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply redefine the `plain` theorem style to ignore the "attribution" part. The default definition is

```
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
```

so you can say

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremlisttype{all}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{problem}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{problem}
\newtheorem{Problem}{Problem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of problems}
\listtheorems{Problem}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{Problem}[Short foo name]
  Foo!
\end{Problem}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{Problem}[Short bar name]
  Bar!
\end{Problem}

\end{document}
```

This is the list:

[image]

and here is the first problem text

[image]

Comment: How did You get the `plain` style definition? I've made it a [separate question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86354/is-there-a-way-i-can-get-the-latex-environment).

Comment: @Adobe I looked in the code of `ntheorem.sty`, searching for `\newtheoremstyle`.

Comment: How do I control space between number and short problem tittle in the list of problems? I tried the following: `\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \hspace{1in} ##2\theorem@separator` -- it compiles but doesn't work.

Comment: Here's the closest I can get: `\makeatletter\def\thm@@thmline#1#2{\@dottedtocline{-2}{0em}{5em}{\protect\numberline{#2}}}\makeatother` (here I'm powered solely by trial-and-error).

Comment: For the spacing, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53353/spacing-for-listtheorems-in-ntheorem

Comment: You right -- it allows one to adjust the horizontal spacing. There's also [an issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98728/ntheorem-vertical-space-between-chapters-in-listtheorems) to adjust the vertical spacing between chapters.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of situation, I'd be tempted to defined my own `environment` rather than hack into the internals of an existing package.

In the code below, I've defined two environments for you to play with, depending on what you want. Both approaches rely on the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) for a few commands- the second environment needs [`xparse`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xparse) for an environment with two optional arguments.

Both environments add to `\jobname.prb` which is created using the `\@starttoc` command.

**Problem**

This environment takes an optional argument, which will be added to `.prb` if not empty.

```
% define the Problem environment
%
% Takes an optional description- if it is not empty, 
% then it is added to \jobname.prb
\newcounter{problem}
\newenvironment{problem}[1][]{\refstepcounter{problem}%
    {\bfseries Problem~\theproblem} %
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
    {% 
        % if #1 is empty, do nothing
    }%
    {%
        % otherwise add it to jobname.prb
        \addcontentsline{prb}{subsection}{#1}%
    }%
}{}
```

This can be used as either

```
\begin{problem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}
```

or

```
\begin{problem}[Description goes here, and added to jobname.prb]
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}
```

**Otherproblem**

This one is a bit more intricate as it takes *two* optional arguments.

```
% define another Problem environment, just for demonstration
%
% Takes TWO optional arguments:
%   #1: long description, used for \jobname.prb if #2 is not present
%   #2: short description, used for \jobname.prb if present
\newcounter{otherproblem}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{otherproblem}{O{} O{}}{\refstepcounter{otherproblem}%
    {\bfseries Problem~\theotherproblem} %
    \ifstrempty{#2}%
    {% 
        % if #2 is empty, then check for #1, and 
        % use it for jobname.prb if present
        \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {%
            % if #1 is empty, do nothing 
        }%
        {%
            % otherwise, display it, and add it to
            % \jobname.prb
            {[\bfseries #1]}%
            \addcontentsline{prb}{subsection}{#1}%
        }%
    }%
    {%
        % if #2 is not empty, use it for the 
        % \jobname.prb
        \addcontentsline{prb}{subsection}{#2}%
        \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {}%
        {%
            {[\bfseries #1]}%
        }%
    }%
}{}
```

Sample usage

```
\begin{otherproblem}[Long description][Short description for list]
\lipsum[2]
\end{otherproblem}
```

or

```
\begin{otherproblem}[Long description displayed and added to list]
\lipsum[2]
\end{otherproblem}
```

or

```
\begin{otherproblem}[][Short description for list, nothing displayed]
\lipsum[2]
\end{otherproblem}
```

Here's the complete MWE to play with- let me know if you need help changing the `style` of the environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

% this sets up \jobname.prb which will store the 
% contentslines added on each problem
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listproblemname{List of problems}
\newcommand\listofproblems{%
  \section*{\listproblemname}\@starttoc{prb}}
\makeatother

% define the Problem environment
%
% Takes an optional description- if it is not empty, 
% then it is added to \jobname.prb
\newcounter{problem}
\newenvironment{problem}[1][]{\refstepcounter{problem}%
    {\bfseries Problem~\theproblem} %
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
    {% 
        % if #1 is empty, do nothing
    }%
    {%
        % otherwise add it to jobname.prb
        \addcontentsline{prb}{subsection}{#1}%
    }%
}{}

% define another Problem environment, just for demonstration
%
% Takes TWO optional arguments:
%   #1: long description, used for \jobname.prb if #2 is not present
%   #2: short description, used for \jobname.prb if present
\newcounter{otherproblem}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{otherproblem}{O{} O{}}{\refstepcounter{otherproblem}%
    {\bfseries Problem~\theotherproblem} %
    \ifstrempty{#2}%
    {% 
        % if #2 is empty, then check for #1, and 
        % use it for jobname.prb if present
        \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {%
            % if #1 is empty, do nothing 
        }%
        {%
            % otherwise, display it, and add it to
            % \jobname.prb
            {[\bfseries #1]}%
            \addcontentsline{prb}{subsection}{#1}%
        }%
    }%
    {%
        % if #2 is not empty, use it for the 
        % \jobname.prb
        \addcontentsline{prb}{subsection}{#2}%
        \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {}%
        {%
            {[\bfseries #1]}%
        }%
    }%
}{}

\begin{document}

\listofproblems

\clearpage

\begin{problem}[Regular problem environment]
\lipsum[1]
\end{problem}

\begin{otherproblem}[Long description][Short description for list]
\lipsum[2]
\end{otherproblem}

\begin{problem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll find time and study Your solution thoughly.