# Is there a way I can get the LaTeX environment?

Tags: macros, environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined)

Is there a way I can get LaTeX environment for a given set-up?

For example I want to get the value of some parameter (such as `\pagewidth`), or a definition of some macros (such as `\@partend`). Can I make LaTeX print that information -- of do I have to go down to the sty files for that?

Comment: what do you mean by get, do you mean use in another macro or returned to you as a user. \showthe\pagewidth or \expandafter\show\csname @partend\endcsname will make tex stop and show those values

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined

Comment: @lockstep: then this question is a duplicate.