# List of theorems: no links when problem title is non-english

Tags: xetex, hyperref, ntheorem

I'm trying to make use of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86271/8992) solution to get list of problems.

I'm using XeTeX, and if I use non-english as a problem name -- hyperref's links to problem in "List of problems" doesn't work.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

% =====================
%% XeTeX customization:

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setromanfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% Russian/English document:
\usepackage{xecyr}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}

\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}


% =======================
%% hyperref and ntheorem:

\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\theoremlisttype{all}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{problem}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{problem}
\newtheorem{Задача}{Задача}[chapter]

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of problems}
\listtheorems{Задача}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{Задача}[Short foo name]
  Foo!
\end{Задача}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{Задача}[Short bar name]
  Bar!
\end{Задача}

\end{document}
```

It needs to be compiled with `xelatex`. I want to get clickable list of problems.

I tried to add some options to hyperref:

```
\hypersetup{xetex,
  unicode=true,
  pdfencoding=unicode,
  bookmarks={true},
}
```

it doesn't work.

**Edit**:

Versions:

```
ntheorem 1.31 
hyperref 6.82q
polyglossia 1.2.1
xecyr 1.0
```

Complete compile log is [here](http://pastebin.com/PUBZnU8K).

**Edit 2**:

Here's thm file on request of egreg:

```
\contentsline {Задача}{{Задача}{1.{1}}{Short foo name}}{3}{Задача.1.1}
\contentsline {Задача}{{Задача}{2.{1}}{Short bar name}}{5}{Задача.2.1}
```

With the solution I posted below the same file is

```
\contentsline {problem}{{Задача}{1.{1}}{Short foo name}}{3}{problem.1.1}
\contentsline {problem}{{Задача}{2.{1}}{Short bar name}}{5}{problem.2.1}
```

Comment: I have no issue. What TeX distribution do you have?

Comment: `texlive` 2012 quantal package. Are You sure You get clickable links in list of problems?

Comment: Yes; I get links named "1.1 Short foo name" and "1.2 Short bar name" that take to "Задача 1.1" and "Задача 1.2", respectively.

Comment: I've posted versions of some packages. What could it be?

Comment: I have `ntheorem` 1.33, `hyperref` 6.83m, `polyglossia` 1.2.1, `xecyr` 1.0; in particular, version 1.32 of `ntheorem` did something about lists of theorems.

Comment: I've updated both `ntheorem` and `hyperref` -- and it doesn't work. [New compile log](http://pastebin.com/vkbpgLf7).

Comment: What I can deduce from the log file is that it's not relative to the minimal example, and it's impossible to go on discussing different things.

Comment: Woops! Sorry -- the log was from the full version. Here's [a log from MWE](http://pastebin.com/0qU5XrVC) -- it doesn't work with MWE also.

Comment: Please, add to your question the contents of `nthe.thm`, that is, the file generated for the list of theorems.

Comment: Does `\texorpdf{...}{...}` help to create links that work?

Answer (score 2):

Oh I solved it:

```
\documentclass{book}

% =====================
%% XeTeX customization:

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setromanfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% Russian/English document:
\usepackage{xecyr}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}

\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}


% =======================
%% hyperref and ntheorem:

\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\theoremlisttype{all}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{problem}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{problem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Задача}[chapter]

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of problems}
\listtheorems{problem}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{problem}[Short foo name]
  Foo!
\end{problem}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{problem}[Short bar name]
  Bar!
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to have `problem` as an internal problem name:

```
\newtheorem{problem}{Задача}[chapter]
```

and generate list of problems with:

```
\listtheorems{problem}
```

Sample problem:

```
\begin{problem}[Short foo name]
  Foo!
\end{problem}
```

Still after compilation I get Задача as a problem name.

Despite this solves the problem I'd like to mention that egreg who have a newer xelatex distriburion don't get an issue at all.