# How can I automatically typeset a list of (theorem-like) definitions?

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems

I've defined two custom types of theorem-like environments: *definition* and *example*. I now want to automatically typeset a list of such environments present in my document. The output I'd like to get would be similar to that obtained with `\listoffigures` and `\tableofcontents`.

How can I automatically typeset a list of such theorem-like environments?

Edit:
Added a mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\newtheorem{bsp}{Beispiel}
\begin{document}
\begin{defi}[Definition1]
foo foo foo
\end{defi}
\begin{bsp}[Example 1]
foo foo foo
\end{bsp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [**This**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/custom-list-of-hypotheses-in-table-of-contents-format) might help.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ntheorem package, which lets you format your theoremlike environments as you want, and additionally has a \listtheorems command, that you could use very simply as follows:

```
 \listtheorems{defi,bsp}
```

See  §2.4 of the ntheorem documentation for details.